# Как преобразовать формат вида 2022-12-06T11:02:03.824+0300 в %d.%m.%Y?

Tags: python, datetime

```
str(datetime.strptime(date, pattern).strftime(to_pattern))
```

пробовал формат

```
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%j%z
```

работает только для такого куска:

```
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
2022-12-06T11:02:03
```

Comment: Ну, просто откусите лишнее после точки, чтобы не мешалось, наверное? Ну или если вам принципиально, возьмите библиотеку [iso8601](https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/) например

Comment: @andreymal похоже так сделать и придется, думал может можно как то паттерн подобрать...

Comment: `pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'`

Comment: @splash58 сработало, спасибо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как Ваш комментарий отметить правильным)

Comment: (меня не покидает чувство, что когда-то такой pattern у меня не работал, но я забыл когда именно)

Comment: давайте сделаю ответ

Comment: @splash58 да, сделайте, пожалуйста)

Comment: @andreymal вспоминайте, а то обману ненароком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для распознавания микросекунд можно использовать паттерн `f`

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '2022-12-06T11:02:03.824+0300'
pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
datetime.strptime(s, pattern)
datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 6, 11, 2, 3, 824000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800)))
```